# Exposing class types directly through another class

Tags: c#

I have a class called Config with the declaration
`public class Config<T> where T : class, new()`

It contains some methods to save a configuration of type `T` as well as the actual configuration in property called `Configuration`.

Is it possible to expose the configuration of type `T` directly in my Config class without having to go through the `Configuration` property.

So far, I have a bit of an ugly work around

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get { return _configuration; }
}
```

If not, then I was wondering if it can be done by inheriting from the `T`, but I'm not clear on the syntax of how to do this.

**Edit:**
I imagined you could do something like

```
public T this
{
    get { return _configuration; }
}
```

Comment: No; that's not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this question, could you post the way you would consume the API and access configuration?

Comment: I have added the way I imagined.

Comment: Does your class CONSUME a T or CREATE one? If it's the latter, you could look at the Builder pattern and return a T via a Build() method. That would give you more flexibility in what actually happens to get a T.

Comment: If you think about it, your imagined-solution would introduce a major ambiguity for the compiler. Suppose you wanted to ASSIGN a Config class instance to a variable - x = myConfig; How could the compiler tell that you really wanted the T?

Comment: 1) It creates a T. 2) x would be of T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx):

```
class Config<T> where T: class, new()
{
  private T _configuration;

  public static implicit operator T(Config cfg)
  {
    return cfg._configuration;
  }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
var config = new Config<SomeClass>();
SomeClass realConfig = config;
```

Comment: Thanks. Though the usage is really the same as having `SomeClass realConfig = config.Configuration;`, except you can cast it: `((SomeClass) config).Property`

Comment: Well yeah, but it saves from having to use the property, which is what I thought you were asking about?

Comment: @lejon Not Exactly.... It's an implicit operator so you can do `SomeClass realConfig = config`;

Answer (score 1):

Use an operator....

```
public static implicit operator T(Config<T> source) {
   return source.Configuration;
}
```

Then

```
MyClass x=new Config<MyClass>();
```